# Cases alignment and displaystyle for all environments

Tags: align, cases

please consider following "minimal" code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}\begin{align*}
(p's_y)(z)&=(ps_xs_y)(z)=\\
    &=\begin{cases}
        p'(z)                       &   z\neq y\\
        \sum_{v\in N(y)}p'(v)-p'(z) &       z=y
    \end{cases}\\
    &=\begin{cases}
        p(z)                                            &   z\neq x,y\\
        \sum_{v\in N(x)}p(v)-p(x)                       &   z=x\\
        \sum_{v\in N(y)\setminus\{x\}}p'(v)+p'(x)-p'(y) &   z=y
    \end{cases}\\
    &=\begin{cases}
        p(z)                                            &   z\neq x,y\\
        \sum_{v\in N(x)}p(v)-p(x)                       &   z=x\\
        \sum_{v\in N(y)\setminus\{x\}} p(v) +
        \sum_{v\in N(x)}p(x)-p(x)-p(y)                  &   z=y
    \end{cases}\\
    &=\begin{cases}
        p(z)                                            &   z\neq x,y\\
        \sum_{v\in N(x)}p(v)-p(x)                       &   z=x\\
        \sum_{v\in N(y)\setminus\{x\}} p(v) +
        \sum_{v\in N(x)\setminus\{y\}} p(v) -p(x)       &   z=y
    \end{cases}\\
    &=\begin{cases}
        p(z)                                                        &   z\neq x,y\\
        \sum_{v\in N(x)}p(v)-p(x)                                   &   z=x\\
        \sum_{v\in \left(N(x)\cup N(y)\right)\setminus\{x,y\}} p(v) &   z=y
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Which turns into following:

[image]

So now to my questions:

1. How can I globally set `\displaystyle` and `\limits` for the whole document and all environments without declaring it again and again (i.e. without explicitly writing `\displaystyle\sum\limits`... every time).
2. How can I make all the condidions (i.e. `z=y`...) align?
3. How can I make the first column of the `cases` (i.e. the summs and `p(x)`) centered?

Comment: `\usepackage{mathtools}` and `dcases` environment.

Comment: However, rather than repeating `cases` I'd split the computations in the three cases and show only a final `cases` (or `dcases`) environment.

Comment: ok thx `dcases` eases problem 1. So theres still 2 and 3 to go. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with `dcases` from the `mathtools` package and measuring the largest item, but the final result is much worse than your image, in my opinion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\newlength{\longestcase}
\newcommand{\longcase}[1]{%
  \mathmakebox[\longestcase][l]{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\longestcase}{%
  $\displaystyle
   \sum_{v\in N(y)\setminus\{x\}} p(v) +
   \sum_{v\in N(x)}p(x)-p(x)-p(y)
  $}
\begin{align*}
(p's_y)(z)
  &=(ps_xs_y)(z)=\\
  &=\begin{dcases}
    \longcase{p'(z)}                                 & z\neq y\\[2ex]
    \sum_{v\in N(y)}p'(v)-p'(z)                      & z=y
    \end{dcases}\\
  &=\begin{dcases}
    \longcase{p(z)}                                  & z\neq x,y\\[2ex]
    \sum_{v\in N(x)}p(v)-p(x)                        & z=x\\
    \sum_{v\in N(y)\setminus\{x\}}p'(v)+p'(x)-p'(y ) & z=y
    \end{dcases}\\
  &=\begin{dcases}
    \longcase{p(z)}                                  & z\neq x,y\\[2ex]
    \sum_{v\in N(x)}p(v)-p(x)                        & z=x\\
    \sum_{v\in N(y)\setminus\{x\}} p(v) +
    \sum_{v\in N(x)}p(x)-p(x)-p(y)                   & z=y
    \end{dcases}\\
  &=\begin{dcases}
    \longcase{p(z)}                                  & z\neq x,y\\[2ex]
    \sum_{v\in N(x)}p(v)-p(x)                        & z=x\\
    \sum_{v\in N(y)\setminus\{x\}} p(v) +
    \sum_{v\in N(x)\setminus\{y\}} p(v) -p(x)        & z=y
    \end{dcases}\\
  &=\begin{dcases}
    \longcase{p(z)}                                  & z\neq x,y\\[2ex]
    \sum_{v\in N(x)}p(v)-p(x)                        & z=x\\
    \sum_{v\in (N(x)\cup N(y))\setminus\{x,y\}} p(v) & z=y
    \end{dcases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[image]

Centering the objects makes it even worse. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\newlength{\longestcase}
\newcommand{\longcase}[1]{%
  \mathmakebox[\longestcase][c]{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\longestcase}{%
  $\displaystyle
   \sum_{v\in N(y)\setminus\{x\}} p(v) +
   \sum_{v\in N(x)}p(x)-p(x)-p(y)
  $}
\begin{align*}
(p's_y)(z)
  &=(ps_xs_y)(z)=\\
  &=\begin{dcases}
    \longcase{p'(z)}                                            & z\neq y\\[2ex]
    \longcase{\sum_{v\in N(y)}p'(v)-p'(z)}                      & z=y
    \end{dcases}\\
  &=\begin{dcases}
    \longcase{p(z)}                                             & z\neq x,y\\[2ex]
    \longcase{\sum_{v\in N(x)}p(v)-p(x)}                        & z=x\\
    \longcase{\sum_{v\in N(y)\setminus\{x\}}p'(v)+p'(x)-p'(y)}  & z=y
    \end{dcases}\\
  &=\begin{dcases}
    \longcase{p(z)}                                             & z\neq x,y\\[2ex]
    \longcase{\sum_{v\in N(x)}p(v)-p(x)}                        & z=x\\
    \longcase{\sum_{v\in N(y)\setminus\{x\}} p(v) +
      \sum_{v\in N(x)}p(x)-p(x)-p(y)}                           & z=y
    \end{dcases}\\
  &=\begin{dcases}
    \longcase{p(z)}                                             & z\neq x,y\\[2ex]
    \longcase{\sum_{v\in N(x)}p(v)-p(x)}                        & z=x\\
    \longcase{\sum_{v\in N(y)\setminus\{x\}} p(v) +
      \sum_{v\in N(x)\setminus\{y\}} p(v) -p(x)}                & z=y
    \end{dcases}\\
  &=\begin{dcases}
    \longcase{p(z)}                                             & z\neq x,y\\[2ex]
    \longcase{\sum_{v\in N(x)}p(v)-p(x)}                        & z=x\\
    \longcase{\sum_{v\in (N(x)\cup N(y))\setminus\{x,y\}} p(v)} & z=y
    \end{dcases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry for not meeting your taste but to me is seems prettier. Anyway... any change to center stuff?

Comment: @zivimo Yes, it's possible to make it arbitrarily ugly. `;-)`

Answer (score 2):

A variant, using the `eqparbox` package to measure the widest left side with a system of tags, and less horizontal space with the `\smashoperator` command from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand\eqmathbox[2][]{\eqmakebox[#1]{\ensuremath{\displaystyle#2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  (p's_y)(z) & =(ps_xs_y)(z)= \\
                                                                                                      & =\begin{dcases}
  \eqmathbox[C]{p'(z)} & z\neq y \\
  \eqmathbox[C]{\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{v\in N(y)}}p'(v)-p'(z)} & z=y
  \end{dcases}\\[1ex]
                                                                                                      & =\begin{dcases}
  \eqmathbox[C]{p(z)} & z\neq x,y \\
  \eqmathbox[C]{\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{v\in N(x)}}p(v)-p(x)} & z=x \\
  \eqmathbox[C]{\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{v\in N(y)\setminus\{x\}}}p'(v)+p'(x)-p'(y)} & z=y
  \end{dcases}\\[1ex]
                                                                                                      & =\begin{dcases}
  \eqmathbox[C]{p(z)} & z\neq x,y \\
  \eqmathbox[C]{\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{v\in N(x)}}p(v)-p(x)} & z=x \\
  \eqmathbox[C]{\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{v\in N(y)\setminus\{x\}}} p(v) +
  \smashoperator{\sum_{v\in N(x)}}p(x)-p(x)-p(y)} & z=y
  \end{dcases}\\[1ex]
                                                                                                      & =\begin{dcases}
  \eqmathbox[C]{p(z)} & z\neq x,y \\
  \eqmathbox[C]{\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{v\in N(x)}}p(v)-p(x)} & z=x \\
  \eqmathbox[C]{\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{v\in N(y)\setminus\{x\}}} p(v) +
  \smashoperator{\sum_{v\in N(x)\setminus\{y\}}} p(v) -p(x)} & z=y
  \end{dcases}\\[1ex]
                                                                                                      & =\begin{dcases}
  \eqmathbox[C]{p(z)} & z\neq x,y \\
  \eqmathbox[C]{\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{v\in N(x)}}p(v)-p(x)} & z=x \\
  \eqmathbox[C]{\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{v\in \left(N(x)\cup N(y)\right)\setminus\{x,y\}}} p(v)} & z=y
  \end{dcases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]